# Failing to push to Knockout observable array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, javascript-objects

I'm trying to push some data to a KO observable array.  I'm getting data from my AJAX call and I get no errors when my script executes.  However, if I try to access `userNames`, I get an empty array.  What am I missing here?

```
UserHandler = (function () {
    var userName = function (data) {
            this.Name = data;
        };

    var userNames = ko.observableArray([]);

    var getUserNames = function () {
            userNames([]);
            $.ajax({
                url: "Users/All",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    ko.utils.arrayPushAll(userNames, $.map(data, function (entry) {
                        return new userName(entry);
                    }));
                }
            });
        };;

    return {
        UserNames: userNames,
        GetUserNames: getUserNames,
    };

});

console.log(UserHandler().UserNames());
   --> []
```

Comment: What happens if you just execute this portion of the code - $.map(data, function (entry) {
                        return new userName(entry);

Comment: I end up with an array of `userName` objects.  I can cycle through them and return the properties of the objects.  Am I doing something wrong with scope possibly?

Answer (score 0):

Observable array in knockout are tricky and sometimes difficult to understand. I can do something like this:

```
ko.utils.arrayPushAll(userNames(), $.map(data, function (entry) {
    return new userName(entry);
}));
userNames.valueHasMutated();
```

or just

```
userNames($.map(data, function (entry) {
    return new userName(entry);
}));
```

In first solution you add parenthesis to get observable raw value and then you manipulate it and notify all subscribers that value was changed.
In second solution you just provide new value of observableArray.

Comment: It still isn't working for some reason.  If I add `console.log(userNames())` to the AJAX success function, I get all the users.  This works with both methods.  But if I try `console.log(UserHandler().UserNames())` outside the object, I get null.

Comment: Every time when you invoke UserHandler() you receive new object. So please assign it to some variable, invoke GetUserNames() wait for result and then your UserNames will have values.